# Reserve Space for ScrollViewer

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I've got a ScrollViewer round some controls and with

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
   ...some controls here...
</ScrollViewer>
```

by default it doesn't reserve the space needed to show the scroll bar. This means that when it's shown/hidden my controls are squished and expanded again.

How can I reserve space for the scroll bar? Is there some kind of property or style I can set which means when it's not needed it's set to hidden rather than collapsed? Or do my child controls need a 'padding' or something on their right hand side to leave the space? Should I put the controls in a grid and make a scroll viewer sized column for the scroll bar to be displayed in (somehow)?

I would like it still to be invisible when not required I would just like the best way of making it reserve the space for when it is.

Thanks all.

Comment: check ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility if helps http://prntscr.com/41jx4u

Answer (score 11, accepted):

here is a sample

this will reserve the scroll bar space when it is not visible by using a border as placeholder

```
    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="auto" x:Name="scroll">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Border Background="LightGoldenrodYellow"
                    Height="300" />
            <Border Grid.Column="1"
                    Width="{x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidth}">
                <Border.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="Border">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility, ElementName=scroll}"
                                         Value="Visible">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility"
                                        Value="Collapsed" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </Border.Style>
            </Border>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

the first border is the content and the second border is the placeholder for reserving the space for scrollbar. you can choose to replace with element of your choice

**Define as a reusable template**

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="ReservedSpaceScroller" TargetType="ContentControl">
            <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="auto"
                          x:Name="scroll">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ContentPresenter />
                    <Border Width="{x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidth}"
                            x:Name="placeholder" Grid.Column="1" />
                </Grid>
            </ScrollViewer>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility, ElementName=scroll}"
                             Value="Visible">
                    <Setter TargetName="placeholder"
                            Property="Visibility"
                            Value="Collapsed" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <ContentControl Template="{StaticResource ReservedSpaceScroller}">
        <Border Background="LightGoldenrodYellow"
                Height="300" />
    </ContentControl>
</Grid>
```

result

[image: result]

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `ScrollViewer` to always 'reserve space' for its `ScrollBar`, then you can do this:

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
    ...some controls here...
</ScrollViewer>
```

This will show the `ScrollBar` even when it is not required, but it will not make your controls *squished and expanded* when it is required.

Comment: Sorry - maybe I should have clarified, I would like it invisible when not required, but just invisible - not collapsed!

Answer (score 0):

I've tried the answer of pushpraj but found out, that there is still a resize happening on the content because `SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidth` gives you just the Width of the pure Scrollbar although it can have Margins to it.

So I came up with a Behaviour which sets directly the Visibility of the ScrollBar. First just create a class called `ScrollViewerHiddenScrollbarsBehaviour` and implement it like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Set the ScrollBars of a ScrollViewer to Hidden (instead of Collasped) when they are not needed.
/// </summary>
/// <seealso cref="MTM.UI.Behaviors.FrameworkElementBehaviorBase{System.Windows.Controls.ScrollViewer}" />
public class ScrollViewerHiddenScrollbarsBehaviour : FrameworkElementBehaviorBase<ScrollViewer>
{
    private ScrollBar _verticalScrollBar;
    private ScrollBar _horizontalScrollBar;

    /// <summary>
    /// Setup the Behaviour
    /// </summary>
    protected override void Setup()
    {
        AssociatedObject.Loaded += OnLoaded;
    }

    private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Getting the ScrollBars IF they are set to ScrollBarVisibility.Auto
        _verticalScrollBar = AssociatedObject.VerticalScrollBarVisibility != ScrollBarVisibility.Auto ? null :
            AssociatedObject.Template.FindName("PART_VerticalScrollBar", AssociatedObject) as ScrollBar;
        _horizontalScrollBar = AssociatedObject.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility != ScrollBarVisibility.Auto ? null :
            AssociatedObject.Template.FindName("PART_HorizontalScrollBar", AssociatedObject) as ScrollBar;

        if (_verticalScrollBar != null) {
            // When changing the Visibility of the ScrollBar directly it won't get updated anymore when the ScrollViewer
            // needs it. So let's do this manually.
            DependencyPropertyDescriptor
              .FromProperty(ScrollViewer.ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibilityProperty, typeof(ScrollViewer))
              .AddValueChanged(AssociatedObject, VerticalHandler);
            VerticalHandler(null, null);
        }
        if (_horizontalScrollBar != null) {
            // When changing the Visibility of the ScrollBar directly it won't get updated anymore when the ScrollViewer
            // needs it. So let's do this manually.
            DependencyPropertyDescriptor
                .FromProperty(ScrollViewer.ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibilityProperty, typeof(ScrollViewer))
                .AddValueChanged(AssociatedObject, HorizontalHandler);
            HorizontalHandler(null, null);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the Visibility of the vertical ScrollBar as needed by the ScrollViewer, BUT Hidden instead of collapsed
    /// </summary>
    private void VerticalHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_verticalScrollBar == null)
            return;

        _verticalScrollBar.Visibility = AssociatedObject.ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility == Visibility.Visible
            ? Visibility.Visible
            : Visibility.Hidden;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the Visibility of the horizontal ScrollBar as needed by the ScrollViewer, BUT Hidden instead of collapsed
    /// </summary>
    private void HorizontalHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_horizontalScrollBar == null)
            return;

        _horizontalScrollBar.Visibility = AssociatedObject.ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility == Visibility.Visible
            ? Visibility.Visible
            : Visibility.Hidden;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Cleanup the Behaviour
    /// </summary>
    protected override void Cleanup()
    {
        AssociatedObject.Loaded -= OnLoaded;

        DependencyPropertyDescriptor
            .FromProperty(ScrollViewer.ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibilityProperty, typeof(ScrollViewer))
            .RemoveValueChanged(AssociatedObject, VerticalHandler);
        DependencyPropertyDescriptor
            .FromProperty(ScrollViewer.ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibilityProperty, typeof(ScrollViewer))
            .RemoveValueChanged(AssociatedObject, HorizontalHandler);
    }
}
```

Usage is as simple as this:

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="auto">
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <behaviors:ScrollViewerHiddenScrollbarsBehaviour />
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>

    <Border Background="LightGoldenrodYellow"
            Height="300" />
    </Border>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Hope this helps